# How to use Dexie to synchronize a MSSQL database using an Order Form

Tags: dexie

I am looking to create an HTML5 Online Order app using Dexie.  The back-end database is MSSQL.  I would like to connect to the SQL DB, load data from one or more tables into an IndexDB and provide a order form for the user to select items to order and then be able submit the order form.

Is this possible with Dexie and how would I implement two-way synchronization to keep inventory totals up-to-date?

If someone can point out the pieces I will need I can research this on my own.  I would not mind some examples as well.

I appreciate any help that is offered.

Regards,

Joe

Comment: Take a look at http://dexie.org/docs/Syncable/Dexie.Syncable.js  

As far as I can tell, though, what you are asking is not trivial.

Comment: Doug, I just discovered that MSSQL 2016 supports JSON out of the box.  Now I need figure out how to use Dexie with MSSQL 2016 via JSON.  Does this seem doable?